# updating seekbar while playing media player is not smooth

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-mediaplayer

As part of the application i m building an audio player with Service and Broadcast to update the media player. everything is fine but the seekbar movement is not smooth. This is how i send the seekbar position from service to activity

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (mp != null) {
            int progress = (mp.getCurrentPosition() * 100)
                    / mp.getDuration();
            Integer i[] = new Integer[3];
            i[0] = mp.getCurrentPosition();
            i[1] = mp.getDuration();
            i[2] = progress;
            try {
                PlayerConstants.PROGRESSBAR_HANDLER
                        .sendMessage(PlayerConstants.PROGRESSBAR_HANDLER
                                .obtainMessage(0, i));
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
};
```

and in the activity, seekbar is updated like this

```
PlayerConstants.PROGRESSBAR_HANDLER = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Integer i[] = (Integer[]) msg.obj;
            seekBar.setProgress(i[2]);
        }
    };
```

how could i modify this code to make the movement smooth.thanks in advance

Comment: Did you solved it? Would be nice, if you publish your solution :)

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030125/when-seekbar-updating-androids-mediaplayer-video-is-not-smooth